# Serial UpVoting/DownVoting

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Recently I have seen some threads regarding serial voting, and I was wondering if all the reputation was reverted, or just part of it.

### Example 1

> - User A posts a question
> - User B answers question.
> - User A loves User B's answer so much he +1's the answer, plus 10 more random answers.

System detect serial up-voting. Does it remove the +100 rep, or does it remove the +90 and User B keep the +10 from User A's question.

### Example 2

> - User A posts question.
> - User B hates it so much, he downvotes the question and 9 other questions posted by User A
> - Once User B has downvoted 6 answers, User C comes along to User A question and thinks wow, this is horrible, and downvotes.

Does User A get  lost reputation restored on the original down-vote, User B and User C original down-vote, or all 11 down-votes.

Comment: There's a time frame considered to identify serial up-/downvotes. Also they'll need to appear from a particular user. If you have other up-/downvotes, these won't be considered by the serial up-/downvote reversal script.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i fail to see how that duplicate applies here

Comment: Fail to see what's your question's all about?

Comment: Well, you are a programmer, what would *you* do?  What hint would you use that reliably indicates that the first vote is "real" and the rest are not?

Comment: @HansPassant thats why this is a question, not an answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

The details of how the serial voting script works are not public, for good reason.

As such, we simply don't know how the system will react in the first case, if the vote on the answer to A's question is part of the series. If that kind of detail were public, users with fraudulent or malicious intent could make use of such information to evade the series being reverted.

Serial voting always applies to the votes from one user for another. How others voted doesn't play in this. In your second scenario, User C's votes are independent from User B's votes.